# Determining the cmake target name of a Conan package

Tags: conan

I feel like there's a gap in the Conan docs: I can add a package to my `conanfile.py`, and it can find it, but when I want to actually use it, it's not at all clear what the corresponding name is for cmake's `find_package` and then for `target_link_libraries`. For example, while zlib does say `find_package(ZLIB)` and `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ZLIB::ZLIB)` https://conan.io/center/zlib?tab=useit&os= that seems to be in docs, and so, e.g., fmt doesn't say anything: ihttps://conan.io/center/fmt?tab=useit

Now, if I look at the "recipe" tab, and squint at the code there's

```
    def package_info(self):
        target = "fmt-header-only" if self.options.header_only else "fmt"
        self.cpp_info.set_property("cmake_file_name", "fmt")
        self.cpp_info.set_property("cmake_target_name", f"fmt::{target}")
        self.cpp_info.set_property("pkg_config_name",  "fmt")
```

which makes me think `cmake_file_name` is `fmt` and so it's `find_package(fmt)` and (assuming `not self.options.header_only`) `target == "fmt"` and so `cmake_target_name` is `fmt::fmt` implying `fmt::fmt` is what `target_link_libraries` needs?

zlib has

```
    def package_info(self):
        self.cpp_info.set_property("cmake_find_mode", "both")
        self.cpp_info.set_property("cmake_file_name", "ZLIB")
        self.cpp_info.set_property("cmake_target_name", "ZLIB::ZLIB")
        self.cpp_info.set_property("pkg_config_name", "zlib")
        ...
```

so I think that's right?

If so, is there a reason conan.io doesn't directly and automatically list this stuff? As a user of a package, what I feel like I need is:

- The Conan package name (e.g., `fmt/8.1.1`)
- The cmake file name (e.g., `fmt`)
- The cmake target name (e.g., `fmt::fmt`)
- The header dir and/or header(s) (e.g. "`fmt/`" or `fmt/core.h`, `fmt/format.h`, etc.

Doesn't Conan know all this stuff? Is there really no place it presents it to me?

Comment: This is done by ConanCenter recipes to try to match the "standard" upstream names. The idea is that in many cases it is not necessary to look for it, because it should be in the library documentation. Otherwise, it is possible to get this information from the Conan terminal output (it will list the target names), or a more detailed information with the ``-g Markdown`` generator, that creates files with instructions.